# Why do I keep getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol"

Tags: java, xml

I've tried all different kind of combinations but I just don't get what it wants from me:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ds><ds>...
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:620)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:177)
```

I've looked at other questions but I don't get what is wrong with my XML.

This is the full XML (with some plain text removed):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ds>
    <ds>
        <cue>ABGB : §§ 786 , 810 , 812 </cue>Die Kosten ... <cue>Anmerkung : </cue>
        ... <cue>Bestätigung von </cue>7 
        <Relation bewertung="1">Ob 56/10a </Relation>= Zak 
        <Relation bewertung="1">2010/773 , 440 </Relation>. 
    </ds>
</ds>
```

The producing code:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder icBuilder;

Document parse = null;

try {
    icBuilder = icFactory.newDocumentBuilder();             
    parse = icBuilder.parse(xmlString);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code too please?

Comment: because your xml **is not** an [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)

Comment: You can't make a URL object from an XML string - needs to be an actual URL

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because the answer is in URL javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: This seems pretty clear, really. What are you actually trying to do?!

Comment: @Mureinik Done.

Comment: you probably want https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html

Comment: Can you show the rest of the stacktrace, then?

Comment: @cricket_007 Added until my call to parse

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250982/no-protocol-malformed-url-exception-thrown-at-me-when-trying-to-parse-an-xml-str)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing a `String` to `icBuilder.parse(xmlString)`, so you're actually invoking [`DocumentBuilder.parse(String uri)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

The method expects an URI and will try to parse it as such, while you're passing it some XML data.

Comment: Why would you even *try* to call it `parseUri()`, am I right?

Comment: this is an explanation why it won't work, but it does not suggest a solution like Mureinik do

Answer (score 7):

The [`parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse-java.lang.String-) method takes a uri pointing to an XML document, not its content.

In order to parse the content, you'll have to construct your own [`InputSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html). E.g.:

```
parse = icBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
```

Comment: Then I get `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.`